# AWK Simple way on my way- Need assistance in bash

Tags: bash, scripts

I have below data in a file and need output like this - I did in very bad/hard way looking for something smart way.

file1.log:

```
A  B  C
1  4  6
2  4  4
```

We should compare col A values i.e is 1 = 2 if so matched else not-matched.

```
a1=$(awk -F "|" '{print $3}' file1.log|xargs|awk '{print $1}')
a2=$(awk -F "|" '{print $3}' file1.log|xargs|awk '{print $2}')
if [[ "$a1" == "$a2" ]]; then
     echo "MATCHED"
else
     echo "NOT-MATCHED"
fi
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You don't describe what your _input_ file (files?) looks like. You don't describe the task. And this looks awfully like a homework assignment.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
awk 'BEGIN {p=""} {if(p==$1) {print "matched"; p=$1} else {print "not matched"; p=$1}}'
 file1.log
```

You get:

```
not matched
not matched
not matched
```

To skip the first line:

```
awk 'BEGIN {p=""} NR>1{if(p==$1) {print "matched"; p=$1} else {print "not matched"; p=$1}
}' file1.log 

not matched
not matched
```

You may need to use NR>2 in the above statement. It all depends on what you are trying to do -- your question is not clear as it is.